# Rotating pickerinput hidden dropdown

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinywidgets

I am trying to rotate pickerinput so that the yaxis selection is right next to it.

I am attaching two examples:

1. Using `shinyWidgets::pickerInput`

[image]

2. Using `shiny::selectInput`

[image]

How do I make the pickerinput dropdown not be hidden behind the plot or appear like the dropdown for selectinput?

Code for example 1:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
shiny::shinyApp(

ui = fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Rotating Picker Input"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins



  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2,
      fluidRow(
        style = "transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-150px) translateY(-50px); width: 350px; ",
        shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
          inputId = "select_y",
          label = "Select Y",
          choices = colnames(mtcars),
          selected = colnames(mtcars)[1],
          options = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE,
            `selected-text-format` = "count > 2"
          ),
          multiple = FALSE
        )
      )
    ),
    column(
      10,
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "select_x",
        label = "Select X",
        choices = colnames(mtcars),
        selected = colnames(mtcars)[1],
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = "count > 2"
        ),
        multiple = FALSE
      )
    )
  )
),
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram 
server = function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R

    ggplot(data = mtcars) + geom_point(aes_string(x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y))
  })
}
)
```

Code for example 2:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
shiny::shinyApp(

ui = fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Rotating Picker Input"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins



  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2,
      fluidRow(
        style = "transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-150px) translateY(-50px); width: 350px; ",
        shiny::selectInput(
          inputId = "select_y",
          label = "Select Y",
          choices = colnames(mtcars),
          selected = colnames(mtcars)[1],
          selectize = FALSE
        )
      )
    ),
    column(
      10,
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "select_x",
        label = "Select X",
        choices = colnames(mtcars),
        selected = colnames(mtcars)[1],
        options = list(
          `actions-box` = TRUE,
          `selected-text-format` = "count > 2"
        ),
        multiple = FALSE
      )
    )
  )
),
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram 
server = function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R

    ggplot(data = mtcars) + geom_point(aes_string(x = input$select_x, y = input$select_y))
  })
}
)
```